# Using .p12 file to send signature and validate using Node Crypto verify

Tags: node.js, openssl, cryptography

I am trying to validate calls to my API from an IOS app. I have generated keys for backend like so:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256\
-passout pass:pass\
-out signature_private_key.pem 2048

openssl rsa \
-in signature_private_key.pem\
-passin pass:pass\
-out signature_public_key.pem\
-outform PEM\
-pubout
```

In the node backend I am validating the call like this:

```
static createSignatureString(bodyString, apiKey, timestamp) {
  const bodyHash = crypto
  .createHash("sha256")
  .update(bodyString)
  .digest("base64");
  return `${bodyHash}:${apiKey}:${timestamp}`;
}

static createSignature(string, privateKey) {
    const sign = crypto.createSign("RSA-SHA256");
    sign.write(string);
    sign.end();
    return sign.sign(privateKey, "base64");
}

static verifySignature(xMessageSignatureString, signature, publicKey) {
    const verify = crypto.createVerify("RSA-SHA256");
    verify.update(xMessageSignatureString);
    verify.end();
    return verify.verify(publicKey, new Buffer(signature, "base64"));
}
```

The mobile app uses a .p12 file to generate a signature and send to the rest API. Given the above how would I generate a .p12 file using openssl that would send a valid signature?

Answer (score 1):

**To create a PKCS12 file you need** the private key (which you have) and **an (X.509) certificate** containing the matching publickey, or if applicable a series of certificates starting with the matching one called a 'chain'. Either you can get this certificate/chain from a CA, or OpenSSL can create a self-signed certificate which uses no chain and which is acceptable to many applications but not all:

```
 openssl req -new -x509 -key privatekeyfile -out certfile [-days N] [-$hash]
```

`-days N` specifies how long you want the cert to be valid; for dummy certs it is common to choose a large value like 3650 for about 10  years, or more, although you can as easily generate a replacement in the future if you need to. It's safest not to go beyond 2037 because some C programs, though fewer than in the past, are still affected by the [Y2038 bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). You can specify the hash used in the self-signature; this doesn't really matter, but some people prefer to avoid the default (SHA1) and use e.g. `-sha256` instead. You can specify the 'subject' name on the commandline if you wish with `-subj`; see the man page. There are also many extensions which *can* be placed in an X.509 certificate, but whether you want any of them and if so which ones and what values varies depending on the application(s) that will use it.

Once you have the cert and privatekey in files:

```
 openssl pkcs12 -export -in certfile -inkey privatekeyfile -out p12file
```

On both of these commands you can specify passwords on the commandline, as you did in the commands you posted, if you prefer; see the man pages and/or usage messages. Remember that this practice makes your passwords temporarily visible to other processes, often including other users if on a shared system.

For clarity: on CA-issued certs the signature hash does matter and should not be SHA1 or weaker, but on root or self-signed certs it normally does not matter.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085, I've tried your solution but no luck. I think where I am confused is where do these keys need to be generated, does it matter? 

- I create the keys locally
- create the .p12  locally
- publish the node application 
- query the rest API with and send a signature using the .p12

Comment: @huge-iguana: it does not matter where a keypair is generated at along as (1) the generation uses appropriate entropy/randomness (2) the receiver/verifier(s?) uses the publickey matching the sender/signer's privatekey (always!) and (3) no one who isn't authorized to sign ever gets the privatekey. The _simplest_ approach to (3) and widely considered best practice is to generate the keypair _on_ the device, system or location what will sign and never copy it anyplace else, but the crypto still works for other more-complicated key management schemes.

Comment: @huge-iguana: the nice thing about RSA is that the signed hash can be recovered. Capture a pair of data and signature and use `openssl rsautl -verify` (with the publickey, conversions as needed, and any hexdump) to see whether the key/signature or data/hash is the problem -- or add them to your Q (use non-sensitive data, and post binary in a protective form such as base64) and we/I will do so.